# Hibernate lazy loading Not working , forcefully needs to be eager loading

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

i was trying to understand container managed transaction. below mentioned is code.

```
@Transactional
    public void saveFees(FeesVO vo) throws Exception {
        logger.info(" --- Finding User with Id ---- " + vo.getUserId());
        User user = userDao.getUserById(Long.parseLong(vo.getUserId()));
        logger.info(" ---- User Found with Id ---  " + user);
        userDao.saveFees(CommonUtil.convertFees(vo, user));
        throw new Exception(" business exception ");
    }
```

Transaction is committed, i was expecting my transction to be rolled back as i can have business exception after save method ? is my understanding right ?

Comment: Checked exceptions does not cause rollback. Please check the documentation. I also quite don't get the relation of the question title to the actual question.

Comment: Ya. Real issue with me is Fees is collection with user entity which is lazy loaded. fetching user does not requires fees objects to be fetched. then why hibernate is firing queries to fetch fees objects associated with user object ?

Comment: Can you rephrase or better describe the question? The title (and now your comment) mentions *lazy loading* but the question body is purely about transaction management.

Answer (score 2):

Only `RuntimeException`s cause a rollback for Spring's transactions. Checked `Exception`s don't trigger a rollback. You can change this via `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)`.

Comment: Thanks. if the code is written at the service layer, should i have try and catch on the controller side ( i am using spring mvc).